# Get tests affected by changes in C#

Tags: c#, testing, reflection, xunit.net

I have a slow running test suite that is under constant development from multiple developers. Every time a change is made to the codebase all tests are rerun. The suite uses XUnit.

I want it so when a change is made to a function, that multiple tests use, we get a list of all the tests affected and run just those tests.

Potential solutions:

- Switch the testing framework to Microsoft's (MSTest) which has this feature built in, though I am unsure if I can export the affected tests to a playlist.
- Use reflection and calculate myself what tests need to be run based upon changes though I feel I would need a before and after of the whole codebase to calculate that.

Is it worth the switch to MSTest, calculating myself, or is there another solution I am unaware of.

Comment: I had not heard of this feature before in MSTest. Can you share a link that describes this feature?

Comment: The closest thing I've heard of for this sort of feature is "Live unit testing", which is a VS Enterprise feature.

Comment: Hello @Igor, the option in VS is under Text Editor > All Languages > Code Lens > Show Tested By. This annotates functions with all the tests that they affect.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2022

Comment: That's a feature of Visual Studio, and shouldn't be tied to MSTest as the the testing framework.

Comment: Hello @gunr2171 I would have hoped so as well but regrettably with this option enabled in our XUnit project we get no such information. Should I mention that the XUnit project was created long before I joined (but it is on latest 2.x)?